# Find the mass of the triangle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A thin triangle has vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,2)$. Let the density function at any given point on the triangle be represented by $\rho(x,y)=1+3x+y$ . What is the mass of this triangle?

> I thought of integrating the expression for density but don't know what to put as values of lower and upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line passing through $(0,2)$ and $(1,0)$ has the equation $y=-2x+2$, so as the $x$ value moves from $0$ to $1$, the $y$ value moves from $0$ to $-2x+2$, so $$m=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2-2x} (1+3x+y) dy dx=\frac{8}{3}.$$